# NoSql Denormalizing strategies for many-to-many, one-to-many scenarios

Tags: mongodb, denormalization, nosql

I have a current normalized scenario where I have the following hierarchy:
Division, User, Client, Project

Every user is assigned to one or more divisions of the company

Every project will be assigned to one or more users that are in the specialized divisions

Every client will have one or more projects going at any given time

I understand how to do this in a normalized manner, but I am having trouble wrapping my mind around how should be organized if I am using mongoDB or one of the other NoSql databases.